# Printing full page webpage with image at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, printing-web-page

I'm trying to print a full page (no margins) webpage with a picture at the bottom of the page. However the picture is not printed since the bottom is bellow the bottom of the page. What do I need to change for the picture to be printed? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tibnor/JDXm9/)

HTML:

```
<div class="page" id="container" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;overflow: hidden;width:210mm;height:297mm;">
<div style="position: absolute; top: 130mm; left: 50mm;">
 <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg" style="width: 100mm; height: 100mm;"></img>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 230mm; left: 50mm;">
 <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg" style="width: 100mm; height: 100mm;"/>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.page {
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
}
```

Comment: set the images to `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`

Comment: I'm using it for printing a map, the position needs to be absolute to place the tiles correctly. At least that's the only solution I know of, but other suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was the position to the img-element:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

such that:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 230mm; left: 50mm;">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg" style="width: 100mm; height: 100mm;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"/>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tibnor/6c4y8/)

Comment: I was trying to achive this in pdfHTML from iText and it worked like a charm! Kudos man

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your images have

```
position: absolute;
```

make them instead have

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

By setting their position to fixed you are telling the browser to always have that object within the window at the given coordinates. Absolute positioning is essentially fixed as well, but instead of being relative to the browser window it is relative to the entire webpage.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the help! But it is not what I want. I'm using it for printing a map, there will therefore be some images that are crossing the border. I can't see how I can use fixed position for this case.